# Value Error for Foregin key field

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to insert data  but am getting ValueError while inserting due to ForeignKey.

```
class Test(models.Model):
test_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
test_code = models.SlugField(max_length=10, name='Code',unique=True)
referance_value = models.CharField(name='Referance', max_length=20)

def __str__(self):
    return self.test_name    

class TestTaken(models.Model):
app_code = models.CharField(max_length=20,unique=True)
user_name = models.CharField(name='Username',max_length=20)
test_names = models.ForeignKey(Test, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
result_value = models.CharField(name='ResultValue',max_length=20)

def __str__(self):
    return self.app_code
```

Below is my View.py

```
    def alltestdata(request):
       if request.method == 'POST':
          app_code = request.POST.getlist('app_code')
          test_name = request.POST.getlist('name')
          test_list = request.POST.getlist('test_list')
          for i, j , k in zip(app_code, test_name, test_list):
              book = TestTaken(app_code=i, ResultValue=j, test_names=k, Username=request.user.username)
              book.save()
   return redirect('lab:Dashboard')
```

Am geting following error

```
     ValueError: Cannot assign "'eeeee'": "TestTaken.test_names" must be a "Test" instance.
```

Comment: Well the error already explains it: `k` is a string (here `'eeee'`), but `test_names` should be a `Test`.

Comment: ValueError: Cannot assign "1": "TestTaken.Test" must be a "Test" instance.

Comment: Just realized there was more wrong with this code than I initially thought.  I'll revise my answer, but can you tell me first: are `app_code`, `test_name`, and `test_list` all lists of strings of the same length?  Why `test_list` but not `name_list`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error holds the answer to your question: `test_names` is a `ForeignKey`, not a string.  To set it from a name, you first need to find the key into the `Test` table.  This can be done with a `get` or `get_or_create`, depending on how you want to handle missing tests.

NOTE: `test_names` is not a very good name for that `ForeignKey` field and probably caused this confusion.  It shouldn't be plural, and points to a `Test` object, not just a name.  You probably want something more like `test`

There is some additional confusion in your code.  First, you seem to have swapped values in your inner iteration (`j` gets its value from `test_name` and is then applied to `ResultValue`, while `k` comes from `test_list` but goes to `test_names` instead).  You can avoid confusion like this by using more explicit variable names.  The second source of confusion is in the variable names `app_code`, `test_name`, and `test_list`, all of which seem to be lists, but only one of them has a name that seems to reflect this.

Combining these points into code, try something like the following.  Note that I have changed some of the names of variables to reflect *what I think you intended*, and I have used a simple `get_or_create`, while you might want something else.  Adjust to suit your needs:

```
# in your model
class Test(models.Model):
    test_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    test_code = models.SlugField(max_length=10, name='Code',unique=True)
    referance_value = models.CharField(name='Referance', max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.test_name    

class TestTaken(models.Model):
    app_code = models.CharField(max_length=20,unique=True)
    user_name = models.CharField(name='Username',max_length=20)
    test = models.ForeignKey(Test, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    result_value = models.CharField(name='ResultValue',max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.app_code

# in View.py
def alltestdata(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
      app_codes = request.POST.getlist('app_code')
      test_names = request.POST.getlist('name')
      scores = request.POST.getlist('test_list')
      for code, test_name, score in zip(app_codes, test_names, scores):
          test_obj, _ = Test.objects.get_or_create(test_name=test_name)
          book = TestTaken(app_code=code, ResultValue=score, test=test_obj, Username=request.user.username)
          book.save()
   return redirect('lab:Dashboard')
```

Comment: ValueError: Cannot assign "1": "TestTaken.Test" must be a "Test" instance.

Comment: rewrote my response based on some guesswork as to your intent